# Phaser.js getting Invalid Phaser state object given

Tags: javascript

I'm currently trying to play around with Phaser 2d game engine.

I currently have this bit of code:

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.10.0
(function() {
  var create, game, preload, update;

  game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, '', {
    preload: preload,
    create: create,
    update: update
  });

  preload = function() {
    return game.load.atlasJSONHash('seyan_f_torch', '../sprite_hashes/seyan_f_torch.png', '../sprite_hashes/seyan_f_torch.json');
  };

  create = function() {
    var seyan_f_torch;
    seyan_f_torch = game.add.sprite(0, 180, 'seyan_f_torch', '00219000.png');
    seyan_f_torch.animations.add('walk-down', Phaser.Animation.generateFrameNames('', 219016, 219023, 9), 10, true, false);
  };

  update = function() {};

}).call(this);
```

Then when I try to load it I get this:

> Invalid Phaser State object given. Must contain at least a one of the required functions: preload, create, update or render phaser.js:34530
>
> Phaser v2.4.6 | Pixi.js v2.2.9 | WebGL | WebAudio     http://phaser.io ♥♥♥
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'game' of undefined phaser.js:29106

Not sure what's wrong here. Any information would be great thanks.

....

Here's the actual CS file:

```
game = new (Phaser.Game)(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, '',
    preload: preload
    create: create
    update: update)
    
    
preload = ->
    game.load.atlasJSONHash 'seyan_f_torch', '../sprite_hashes/seyan_f_torch.png', '../sprite_hashes/seyan_f_torch.json' 

create = ->
    # Create Seyan_F_Torch
    seyan_f_torch = game.add.sprite(0, 180, 'seyan_f_torch', '00219000.png')
    seyan_f_torch.animations.add('walk-down', Phaser.Animation.generateFrameNames('', 219016, 219023, 9), 10, true, false);
    setTimeout ->


update = ->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't CoffeeScript, but I have thought the problem is that you're not passing an Object to the Game constructor. Phaser requires a well formatted State Object to start from. You can find an example in the Phaser.State class (in the repo its in src/core/State.js). Likely all you need to do is this:

```
game = new (Phaser.Game)(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, '',
    { preload: preload,
    create: create,
    update: update}
)
```

Comment: Thanks I meant to come back and edit my question, this was the case because cs was converting my functions into function expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and found out, that the function syntax is important for Phaser.

Instead of

```
preload = function() {
};
```

it needs to be

```
function preload() {
};
```